# How to implement sum of data in datastore (represent in the webpage)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, datastore

I am going to make a site about manage and keep track of my money with google app engine.

but i met some problems. like how can i represent my sum of money by using query in datastore

here is my code, i don't know how to deal with the sum_deal stuff

thanks for viewing :)

```
class BlogHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def write(self, *a, **kw):
        self.response.out.write(*a, **kw)

    def render_str(self, template, **params):
        params['user'] = self.user
        return render_str(template, **params)

    def render(self, template, **kw):
        self.write(self.render_str(template, **kw))

class Book(db.Model):
    deal = db.FloatProperty(required= True)
    created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    sum_deal = db.FloatProperty

class BookMe(BlogHandler):
    def render_book(self, deal="",sum_deal=""):
        deals = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Book ORDER BY created DESC")
        self.render("book.html", deal=deal, sum_deal=sum_deal,deals = deals)

    def get(self):
        render_book()

    def post(self):
        deal = self.request.get("deal")
        if deal:
            b = Book(deal = deal)
            b.put()
            self.redirect("/")
```

Comment: what specifically does your code not do correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, don't use floats to represent currency amounts - you'll be subject to all sorts of errors due to floating-point representation. Use decimals.

Secondly, this question shouldn't be particularly difficult. The datastore has no support for aggregation, but you can easily do this in your view: just iterate through all the elements in  `deals` and add up the contents of `deal` for each one.